# Production settings for Rabbit MQ 3.6.0

Tags: rabbitmq

I am configuring Rabbitmq 3.6.0 on production environment. can you please suggest what all required parameters we need to set for this, so that it would work fine on production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a few resources you can read:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/production-checklist.html

and / or

https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html

There is not "production" setting, basically it depends what are you looking for.